# Symbolic links with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

It seems to me that Spark Streaming doesn't read symbolic links. Can someone of you confirm/contradict that please?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: did you find out about this?

Comment: No, I didn’t. It’s an old issue, that probably I solved by using real links